# Splitting a string_view using ranges

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I have a string containing a sequence of numbers separated with the `,` character. To read values from the sequence into an array I created the following code the GCC 10 refuses to compile:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>
#include <charconv>
#include <array>

template<std::size_t Sz>
bool to_bytes(std::array<std::uint8_t, Sz> &data, std::string_view string) {
    auto target = data.rbegin();
    for (const auto octet : string | std::views::split('.')) {
        if (target == data.rend()) {
            return false;
        }

        const auto octet_begin = octet.data();
        const auto octet_end = octet_begin + octet.size();
        const auto error = std::error_code(std::from_chars(octet_begin, octet_end, *target).ec);
        if (error) {
            return false;
        }

        ++target;
    }

    return target == data.rend();
}
```

Briefly speaking the compiler complains that there are no `data()` and `size()` methods available for the type of the `octet` variable. Do I misunderstand that type of `octet` should meet the `contiguous_range` criteria as the `string_view` does? It seems to be argumentative from my POV.

Comment: don't use `string` as a variable name. it's too close to `std::string` you're using

Comment: do you really need `std::string_view` here? why not plain `std::string`?

Comment: It might be a piece of a larger string, question there is not about using something instead of string_view, it's about how to do it using ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the adoption of [P2210](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2210r2.html) as a defect report against C++20, `views::split` can now preserve contiguity, so the above code is now valid and [compiles on gcc trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/YqW8x55Pc).

---

> Do I misunderstand that type of `octet` should meet the `contiguous_range` criteria as the `string_view` does?

Yes. `octet` is *not* a `contiguous_range`. The inner range of a `split_view` is never stronger than a `forward_range` - it is only ever a `forward_range` or an `input_range`.

This makes `views::split` exceedingly awkward to use for any kind of non-trivial parsing - precisely because, as you demonstrate in the question, you can't use things like `from_chars` (or `scanf` or ... ) unless you then manually produce a contiguous range out of it.